How to achieve parallel routing in nextjs inside catch all segment?

You can see the project folder structure i am using in next js. I am currently working on parallel routing concept in nextjs but i am getting trouble in loading teh parallel routing pages they are not even rendering.
Below is my layout folder other pages are just dummy without any content just hello printed in tsx format.
import ProductCategory from "@/app/fragments/authPage/ProductCategory";
import Navbar from "@/app/reusable-components/Navbar";

const layout = ({
    children,
    filter
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    filter: React.ReactNode;

}) => {
    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#F1F3F6', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>

            <Navbar cart={false} />
            <ProductCategory />

            <div>
                hello
                {children}
            </div>
            <div>
                {filter}

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default layout

Try :
i am trying to load the filter parallel route page inside page.tsx or layout.tsx but its not rendering there is no error i am displayed i dont know what to do i have seen video tutorials but its the same thing i am doing but still.
i have hard referesh the browsesr but no use please help me with this............?
